# I'd like to use "Rick Roll" on a German test

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

as in the title of the post. I saw it used as "rick rollst" and "gerick rolled" in a Reddit post. Would it be considered a mistake if I used it on a test? And how should I do it? (Screenshot of the Reddit thread:  https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/454245855059378176/660992496507027466/Screenshot_20191230-004803.png?width=380&height=676)

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what a *Rick Roll* or *rick rollst* or *gerick rolled* are supposed to be. These are not German phrases.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining! It's a reference to a meme called "Rick Roll", (Here's more about it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling)

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you searching for a translation of "Rick Roll"? What you mentioned above, "rick rollst" and "gerick rolled", sound like forms of a verb "rickrollen". "Du rickrollst ihn. Er wurde gerickrollt." I don’t think, however, that this will be very well understood. (I had to look rick rolling up.)

Comment: I'm searching for a translaslation and conjugation of it, sorry for making my question unclear.

Comment: @Nekuś https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/rickroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be considered a mistake if I used it on a test?

This is impossible to answer. It depends on your teacher. If your teacher is not familiar with it, they will probably mark it as a mistake. And even if you explain this afterwards, they might be not open for internet bullshit.  So do it at your own risk.

### **But how would we write this phenomenon correctly?**

Checking the German version of Wikipedia is an obvious start and we find

> „You have been Rickrolled“ (dt.: „Du bist gerickrollt worden“)

Starting from the English *(to) Rickroll* we add -en to make it a German verb. In this process we also let go of the capitalisation, which yields *rickrollen*. Following common German declination rules, the participle becomes **gerickrollt**.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question very well.